# clang vs gcc - empty generic lambda variadic argument pack

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, clang, c++14

I think I found another *"clang vs gcc"* inconsistency between lambdas and callable objects.

`decltype(l)::operator()` should be equivalent to `C::operator()`, but if variadic pack is left empty in the generic lambda, gcc refuses to compile:

> 15 : error: no match for call to '(main()::) (int)'
>   l(1);
>
> 15 : note: candidate: decltype (((main()::)0u).main()::(x, )) (*)(auto:1&&, auto:2&&, ...)
>
> 15 : note: candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
>
> 14 : note: candidate: template main()::
>
> auto l = [](auto&& x, auto&&...) { return x; };
>
> 14 : note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>
> 15 : note: candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
>
> l(1);

[Live example on godbolt.org](https://goo.gl/2ikAUK).

```
struct C
{
    template<typename T, typename... TRest>
    auto operator()(T&& x, TRest&&...){ return x; }
};

int main()
{
    // Compiles both with clang and gcc.
    auto c = C{};
    c(1);

    // Compiles with clang 3.7.
    // Does not compile with gcc 5.2.
    auto l = [](auto&& x, auto&&...) { return x; };
    l(1);
}
```

Could not find anything related to this on the gcc bug tracker *(didn't spend too much time searching though)* - is gcc wrong here?

Comment: Looks like a gcc bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reported the issue as gcc bug [#68071](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68071).