# Incorrect copy constructor while passing argument to generic lambda

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, auto, generic-lambda

Consider this piece of code:

```
template < auto What >
constexpr auto Identity = [](auto&&...) { return What; };

struct Ban
{
  Ban() = default;
  Ban(const Ban&  ban) = delete;
  Ban(      Ban&& ban) = delete;
};

int main()
{ 
  Ban ban;
  Identity<false>(10,ban);

  return 0;
}
```

This fails to compile on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/OmJRwp) with `gcc-7.3` as it tries to copy the second argument of `Identity`. Why it should? Is this a bug in `gcc`?

`gcc` does not complain if the second argument is a temporary or when there is only one argument. It complains for only one argument when the definition of `Identity` is with `(...)` instead of `(auto&&...)`.

Comment: Might indeed be a bug, gcc-8 and clang happily compile this.

Comment: Surprisingly `gcc-8` fails when changing `(auto&&...)` to just `(...)`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first half is a mis-parse of `auto&&...` for generic lambdas in older GCC versions: [clang vs gcc - empty generic lambda variadic argument pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305208/clang-vs-gcc-empty-generic-lambda-variadic-argument-pack?rq=1); [Should non-capturing generic lambdas decay to function pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41317113/should-non-capturing-generic-lambdas-decay-to-function-pointers); [Should non-capturing generic lambdas decay to function pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41317113/should-non-capturing-generic-lambdas-decay-to-function-pointers)

The second half is expected. Passing over C-style `...` variadics makes a copy and you deleted your copy constructor.

Comment: As a suggestion, include the easy fix: `[](auto&&...x)` giving the unused pack a name.